# vlans communicate with each other

Tags: networking, cisco, routing, router, vlan

I am setting up three vlans in a cisco router with the following configurations.

Vlan 10

```
Subnet: 192.168.1.0/24
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

Vlan 20

```
Subnet: 192.168.2.0/24
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.2.1
```

Vlan 30

```
Subnet: 192.168.3.0/24
Netmask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.3.1
```

On vlan 10 is a repository, that the other vlans needs to be able to access. How do i configure the vlans so that vlan 20, 30 can talk to vlan 10?

Comment: With a router, like you would any other three separate subnets.

Comment: @NickW Thanks for the quick response. The vlans are hosted on a router? So do i need to configure the ports then?

Comment: Yes, you just need to consider each VLAN like a switch, with its own network, and create routes between them, I imagine that cisco has something else that might need to be configured, I'm no cisco expert..

Answer (score 0):

I'm much more conversant with HP ProCurves but I think Cisco works the same way in this respect. Each VLAN has its own IP address that you can use as a gateway to that subnet. You either need to publish a route to those subnets to your clients or to re-enable `ip routing` on your switch so that your switch will route between the directly-connected interfaces.

See: [Configure InterVLAN Communication](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/tech/tk389/tk815/technologies_configuration_example09186a008019e74e.shtml)